# Diffuse material that doesn't throw shades in cycles engine

Tags: light, shaders, transparency

I have an object, that has diffuse shader and looks great. Unfortunately it throws some shades on the objects behind it and it looks terrible. Is there any way to make the light to be fully reflected and passed through the object in the same time?

Comment: in cycles : in the object tab --> ray visibility -->shadow   ,uncheck this option

Comment: @Chebhou Post that as an answer please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent an object from casting shadows uncheck the shadow option in  **Object_Tab**--> **Ray_Visibility**--> **Shadow** :

[image]